# In Twitter bootstrap, how do I stop divs from being arranged vertically when I decrease the size of my browser?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three carousels of `span4` and I don't want them to be arranged vertically when I shrink the webpage to a tablet size. I want that to happen when I shrink the web page to phone size instead.

Because, when my browser is in tablet size the carousels are vertically placed and are stretched (which I don't want). Here is my code:

```
div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span4 w" >
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" style="overflow: hidden">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <!-- Carousel items -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="active item">
                            <img class="carouselImg" src="fall.jpg"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item"> <img class="carouselImg"  src="clock8.jpg"/></div>
                        <div class="item"> <img  class="carouselImg" src="color.jpg"/></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Carousel nav -->
                    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
<div class="span4 w">
            <div id="myCarousel1" class="carousel slide" style="overflow: hidden">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <!-- Carousel items -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="active item"> <img class="carouselImg"  src="color.jpg"/></div>
                    <div class="item"> <img class="carouselImg"  src="dots.jpg"/></div>
                    <div class="item"> <img class="carouselImg"  src="light.jpg"/></div>
                </div>
                <!-- Carousel nav -->

            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="span4 w">
            <div id="myCarousel2" class="carousel slide " style="overflow: hidden">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <!-- Carousel items -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="active item"> <img class="carouselImg"  src="ball.jpg"/></div>
                    <div class="item"> <img class="carouselImg"  src="fall.jpg"/></div>
                    <div class="item"> <img class="carouselImg"  src="ball.jpg"/></div>
                </div>
                <!-- Carousel nav -->
                <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel2" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel2" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you using CSS or LESS ? Have you tried to customize the grid ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `row-fluid` class on the containing div. just use `class="row"`.

Using `row-fluid` turns on the fluid/adaptive layout that will rearrange the columns based on viewport size.

**UPDATE**

Have a read here http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem this explains how the grid system works.  Are you including the responsive CSS file? If so, simply removing it should make it stop that.

Comment: I tried that, but that still does the same thing, it arranges the vertically when i don't want them to. There has to be some thing in the CSS files in twitter bootstrap that allow us change the width. I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a @media query like this in your CSS...

```
@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .row-fluid .span4 {
        width:31%;
        float:left;
        margin:4px;
    }
}
```

This will override the Bootstrap CSS for `.row-fluid span4`. You may need to tweak the width/margin of your .span4's accordingly.

Demo: **http://www.bootply.com/64736**